# Searching with paging in telerik mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, grid, telerik, paging

Actually this is related to telerik mvc extension grid.In my telerik grid i have an search text box.i write something in text box and press enter,fire a java script function,from the function i call...ajaxrequest function of grid to rebind the grid for the search.That the simple process.
ok.suppose i am in last page in grid.then i write something in the search textbox and press enter,the search is ok.but the paging is not in correct position.i need to go to the first page in this situation...keypresss enter event is bellow

```
   function ListSearch(keyCode, gridObj)
{
    window.CurrentList = gridObj;
    var id = '#' + $(gridObj).attr('id');
    var searchTxt = $(id + " .watermark-list-search").val();
    var searchList = $(id + " .watermark-list-search").attr('listtype');
    var filterid = $(id + " .watermark-list-search").attr('filterid');

    window.CurrentList.data("tGrid").ajaxRequest({ Name: searchTxt, Data: searchList, id: filterid });
}
```

i modified the code to include page in ajaxrequest like

```
window.CurrentList.data("tGrid").ajaxRequest({ Name: searchTxt, Data: searchList, id: filterid,page:1 });
```

it works i.e getting correct data from database but the current page is wrong and showing wrong status '31 to 60 out of 120 ' instead of '1 to 30 out of 20'

what is the process to make it correct?please let me know

Answer (score 0):

After completing the filter request. Please add below code snippet. It will automatically set surrent page '1' in your grid.

```
window.CurrentList.data("tGrid").pageTo(1);
```

Comment: Thanks Jayesh.ok.It will initiate two requests to server.u said 'After completing the filter request'-is their any way to ensure that the filter request is complete after ajaxRequest?

Comment: Can you please write above code snippet after ajaxrequest code snippet? Please let me know it is working or not.

Comment: thanks again.some times it works and some time it doesn't.PageTo call initiates before completing of ajaxRequest.PageTo should call after getting success/response form ajaxRequest.isn't it?

Comment: Please write page setting code in to complete event. If needed then please add one variable in your page. On searching set its value as true. In complete event if its value true then execute the above code snippet and set its value false. Please check also check below link to know about client api of telerik MVC grid. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnComplete